# Generic interface with wildcard. '? extends Class' is not 'Class'

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning Java and trying to implement a command bus but I'm really stuck on generics and wildcards.

Here's the `CommandHandler` interface:

```
public interface CommandHandler<C extends Command> {

    boolean supports(Command command);

    void handle(C command);
}
```

`CommandBus` interface:

```
public interface CommandBus {

    void register(CommandHandler<? extends Command> handler);

    void handle(Command command);
}
```

And the implementation of `CommandBus`:

```
public class SimpleCommandBus implements CommandBus {

    private List<CommandHandler<? extends Command>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void register(CommandHandler<? extends Command> handler) {
        handlers.add(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Command command) {
        for (CommandHandler<? extends Command> handler : handlers) {
            if (handler.supports(command)) {
                handler.handle(command); // <- problem here

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies on this line: `handler.handle(command);`.

`? extends Command` is not `Command`.
I've tried many things. The only solution that worked is casting:

```
public void handle(Command command) {
    for (CommandHandler<? extends Command> handler : handlers) {
        CommandHandler<Command> castedHandler = (CommandHandler<Command>) handler;

        if (castedHandler.supports(command)) {
            castedHandler.handle(command);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But I think there must be better way to do it.

Comment: Did you try changing Command in `CommandHandler#supports(...)` to accept `C` (the generic parameter) instead?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx But then it will always return `true`, no need to check then.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same issue now and I can't figure out the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that generics only happen at compile-time (in the static type system), but the run-time call to `supports` does not give the compiler information that the type of the handler can now be narrowed. Just like you still have to cast inside of an `if (a instanceof X){` (and that is even a built-in language feature).

Living with the cast is a perfectly pragmatic solution, as you know it is safe, even if the compiler does not.

But if you want to push it further into typesafe country, how about something like this (pseudo-code):

```
public void <C extends Command> handle(C command) {
  handlers.toStream().flatMap(h -> h.adapt(command)).first.handle(command);
}
```

For this you need to make a method on `CommandHandler` (to replace `supports`)

```
<D extends Command> Optional<CommandHandler<D>> adapt(D command);
```

which returns the handler itself with the narrowed type (if it supports that) or an empty Optional if it does not.

That way, the result of the supports/adapt runtime check is expressed in the static type of that result, and the compiler can make use of that.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the type

```
? extends Command
```

as "some specific but unknown subtype of `Command`".

So, each `CommandHandler` in the list handles some specific but unknown subtype of `Command`.
You're passing an argument of type `Command`, but there is no way the compiler will agree that a particular `CommandHandler` will handle this type, since the compiler doesn't know which type it handles at all.

Since your `supports` method takes in any `Command`, it must probably do a type check.  What you could do is have it return `Optional<C>` instead of `boolean`.  An empty `Optional` if the type does not matches, a non-empty one created using a cast after an `instanceof` check.  Then use it like this:

```
handler.supports(command)
       .ifPresent(supportedCommand -> handler.handle(supportedCommand));
```

But you could then ask why even use two methods.  You could just call `handle` and make it return `true` or `false` indicating the command was supported or not.  It would make type parameter `C` obsolete.

You see, the fact that you have a method `supports` which takes `Command` instead of `C` means that you expect clients to not know whether the type matches.  Having a `handle` method that requires a matching type at compile time doesn't make much sense then.